# Httpcontext in service layer with iis integrated

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-7.5

I an asp net web forms application with a service layer in a separate project that handles business logic. One piece performs event tracking which stores, among other things a bunch of stuff about the request. To do this I use Httpcontext. In iis classic mode this works. In integrated pipeline mode it fails. If I can't use Httpcontext here, how can I access this information while in integrated mode?

Comment: [Migrate ASP.NET Applications to IIS 7 Integrated Mode](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2944.migrate-asp-net-applications-to-iis-7-integrated-mode.aspx)? Hth...

Comment: I'm not using it in Application_Start. I'm using it in a separate class project. Are those two concepts related in a way I am unaware of?